# Example that fail to be $\lambda$-measurable

Tags: measure-theory

I am looking at this definition:

> Given an outer measure $\lambda$ on $X$, we called a subset $A$ in $X$ $\lambda$-measurable if for every subset $B \subset X$, $$\lambda(B)=\lambda(B \cap A) + \lambda(B \cap A^c)$$

Is there any example that a subset fail to be $\lambda$-measurable?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it depends on the outer measure. In some cases every set is measurable--consider the measure $\lambda$ on $\mathbb R$ defined by $\lambda(E) = 1$ if $0 \in E$ and $\lambda(E) = 0$ otherwise. In others (such as the Lebesgue measure on the line) there exist nonmeasurable sets.

Comment: I had not considered how different outer measures can impact the use of Caratheodory's Criterion in determining measurable sets. Good observation!

Answer (score 0):

Given an outer measure as the infimum length of open interval covers, the condition you define (the Caratheodory Criterion) tells us which sets are Lebesgue measurable. So every set that is Lebesgue measurable satisfies the Caratheodory Criterion and every set that satisfies the Caratheodory Criterion is Lebesgue measurable. Since there are sets that are not Lebesgue measurable, then those are precisely the sets that don't satisfy your condition.